# Django access/manipulate CreateView uploads

Tags: python, django

I have an CreateView as follows:

```
class SpaceCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Space
    fields = ['title', 'space_image']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I would like to pass the space_image to an 3rd party API and get back the response from there. How should I go about this since I have this set up inside an CreateView?

Answer (score 0):

You can define another function in your class based view for the needed 3rd party API logic like so:

```
class SpaceCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Space
    fields = ['title', 'space_image']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        api_response = call_api(self, form)
        return (super().form_valid(form), api_response)

    def call_api(self, form):
        image_to_forward = form.space_image
        
        # 3rd party API Request logic
        request_api = [...] # However you have to forward the image to the 3rd party API
        response = [...] # Depends on the way the 3rd party API returns the content
        return (response)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there a specific way I should send the image to the api in Django or can I just use post?

Comment: @Daniel you would have to use the requests library or something similar if you want to make an AJAX call to the other API.

Comment: @Jonas, but this would never call the call_api method itself. Shouldn't a call be made to the call_api method inside the form_valid method?

Comment: Hmm, just observed this and indeed the call_api function seems not to be triggered.

Comment: facepalm...time for a break

Comment: what you return depends on how your overall business logic is then